# How would I wait for a series of async tasks to complete in js?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to perform a `GET` request to an API multiple times in a function. I then need to handle all the responses as a whole once they have all yielded responses. What is the best JS design to do this?

**edit:** I originally asked for a `Promise.all()` polyfill. But I feel like I don't need all the functionality of promises and looking for a simpler solution.

I basically need `Promise.all(iterable);` functionailty in native JS.

Comment: https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Comment: Do you need full promise like support, or just the ability to wait for a series of async tasks to complete?

Comment: A callback would be fine. So yes just the ability to wait for a series of async tasks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a polyfill for Promise.all

```
 Promise.all = function (arr) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arr);

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (args.length === 0) return resolve([]);
      var remaining = args.length;

      function res(i, val) {
        try {
          if (val && (typeof val === 'object' || typeof val === 'function')) {
            var then = val.then;
            if (typeof then === 'function') {
              then.call(val, function (val) {
                res(i, val);
              }, reject);
              return;
            }
          }
          args[i] = val;
          if (--remaining === 0) {
            resolve(args);
          }
        } catch (ex) {
          reject(ex);
        }
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        res(i, args[i]);
      }
    });
  };
```

This code is a part of [this](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill/blob/master/promise.js) library.

Comment: I feel like I don't need all the functionality of promises. Thank you for your answer but I'm looking for a simpler solution. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: I posted this as a mean for you to get an idea for polyfilling the `all` function of the `Promise`